# Lifetime inference problem when implementing iterator with refs

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

I'm implementing a simple Iterator for a struct that contains a ref:

```
extern crate zip;
extern crate quick_xml;
extern crate chrono;

use std::io::{Seek, Write, Read, Error};
use std::fs::File;
use xlsx_read::zip::read::ZipFile;
use xlsx_read::zip::result::ZipResult;
use xlsx_read::zip::ZipArchive;
use xlsx_read::zip::write::{FileOptions, ZipWriter};
use xlsx_read::quick_xml::Reader as XmlReader;
use xlsx_read::quick_xml::events::Event;
use std::io::BufReader;
use xlsx_read::chrono::prelude::*;

pub struct XlsxFile<'a> {
    path: &'a str,
    archive: ZipArchive<File>,
    sheet_count: usize,
    curr: usize,
}

impl<'a> XlsxFile<'a> {
    pub fn from(path: &'a str) -> Result<XlsxFile, Error> {
        let file = File::open(path)?;
        let archive = ZipArchive::new(file)?;
        let sheet_count = archive.len();

        Ok(XlsxFile {
            path: path,
            archive: archive,
            sheet_count,
            curr: 0,
        })
    }
}

pub struct XlsxSheet<'a> {
    pub name: &'a str,
    pub index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for XlsxFile<'a> {
    type Item = XlsxSheet<'a>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<XlsxSheet<'a>> {
        loop {
            if self.sheet_count > 0 &&
                self.sheet_count > self.curr {
                let zip_file = self.archive.by_index(self.curr).unwrap();
                let file_name = zip_file.name();
                if file_name.contains("xl/worksheets/sheet") {
                    let sheet = XlsxSheet {
                        name: file_name, // works fine if String::from(file_name) is used
                        index: self.curr,
                    };
                    self.curr += 1;
                    return Some(sheet);
                }
                self.curr += 1;
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return None;
    }
}

static XLSX_FILE: &'static str = "<location_to_xlsx_file>";

fn main() {
    let mut file = xlsx_read::XlsxFile::from(XLSX_FILE).unwrap();

    file.for_each(|s| println!("idx: {:?}", s.name));
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/xlsx_read.rs:50:45
   |
50 |                 let zip_file = self.archive.by_index(self.curr).unwrap();
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 46:5...
  --> src/xlsx_read.rs:46:5
   |
46 | /     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<XlsxSheet<'a>> {
47 | |         loop {
48 | |             if self.sheet_count > 0 &&
49 | |                 self.sheet_count > self.curr {
...  |
66 | |         return None;
67 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/xlsx_read.rs:50:32
   |
50 |                 let zip_file = self.archive.by_index(self.curr).unwrap();
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 43:1...
  --> src/xlsx_read.rs:43:1
   |
43 | impl<'a> Iterator for XlsxFile<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected std::option::Option<xlsx_read::XlsxSheet<'a>>
              found std::option::Option<xlsx_read::XlsxSheet<'_>>

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.
```

My question is, how to tell Rust compiler to use appropriate lifetime here? Even though I've defined XlsxSheet<'a> with lifetime modifier and want to tie name to &'a str but somehow this doesn't translate into a valid Rust code.

Comment: On the Rust tag it is usual to include all necessary `use` in the code example, and when appropriate, a link to [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org//) as well. This helps people that want to answer the question to help you! Right now I don't have time to find those missing `use` and make some tests, but looking quickly, it looks like you are missing a lifetime on `self` itself: `fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<XlsxSheet<'a>>`

Comment: @mcarton I've added import statements and a main method. I also tried to use `fn next(&'a mut self)` but then it started giving me different error msg. 
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/xlsx_read.rs:46:5
   |
46 |     fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<XlsxSheet<'a>> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&mut xlsx_read::XlsxFile<'a>) -> std::option::Option<xlsx_read::XlsxSheet<'_>>`
              found type `fn(&'a mut xlsx_read::XlsxFile<'a>) -> std::option::Option<xlsx_read::XlsxSheet<'a>>`

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Solution**: This problem can be trivially fixed by using `String` instead of `&'a str`.

**Explanation**:

I don't know the definition of `by_index`, which seems to be quite crucial to this problem. The following reasoning is pure guess and it's not reliable. It's offered only for reference.

1. `self.archive` borrows `self` (which is valid over the entire scope, let's say the lifetime is named `'me`), and has lifetime `'me`.
2. Thus the return value of `by_index` has lifetime `'me`.
3. Oops, `XlsxSheet<'me>` is not compatible with `XlsxSheet<'a>` (which is expected)!

What we want here is `XlsxSheet<'me>` being a subtype of `XlsxSheet<'a>`, which in turn implies `'me` being a subtype of `'a`, if `XlsxSheet` is covariant. Therefore, you can state them explicitly

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<XlsxSheet<'a>> where Self: 'a
// or
impl<'a> Iterator for XlsxFile<'a> + 'a
```

Comment: I've already commented the line where the easy solution can be used (`// works fine if String::from(file_name) is used`). I'm actually looking to explore lifetimes in Rust much deeper with this problem.
The other approaches don't compile successfully.